# Discord bot that sends an message to a channel whenever a message is deleted. Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I’m trying to make my bot send a message to a channel whenever a user deletes his/her message, sorta like the bot Dyno, but I do not know how to do this. I think the method is `.deleted()` but I can’t seem to make it work. Can anyone tell me how? Sorry for lack of detail, there’s nothing else to add. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client (or Bot) has an event called [messageDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDelete) which is fired everytime a message is deleted. The given parameter with this event is the message that has been deleted. Take a look at the sample code below for an example.

```js
// Create an event listener for deleted messages
client.on('messageDelete', message => {
  // Fetch the designated channel on a server
  const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'deleted-messages-log');

  // Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
  if (!channel) return;

  // Send a message in the log channel
  channel.send(`A message has been deleted. The message was: ${message.content}`);
});
```